# Get data of a GameObjects' properties affected by Animation Clip at specified frame

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: Inspector providing data based on animation clip]

I have a GameObject called `HitboxObject`. `HitboxObject` has a component called `Hitbox` and `Hitbox`, has a public Vector2 variable named `offset`. An AnimaitonClip modifies the value of `offset` of `HitboxObjects`' `Hitbox` component. I want to get the values of `offset` at different frames through the script. This process does not have to happen on runtime and it has to provide me the information while the animation is not playing.

I tried to use the [SampleAnimation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip.SampleAnimation.html) method of [AnimationClip](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip.html) class;

```cs
    [SerializeField] private AnimationClip attackBoxAnimaiton;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject hitbox;
    [SerializeField] private int frameIndex;

    void Start()
    {
        // Sample the animation clip at the specified frame index
        attackBoxAnimaiton.SampleAnimation(hitbox, GetTimeFromFrame(frameIndex));

        // Extract the data from the target object as needed
        // For example, you can access the position and rotation
        Hitbox hitboxComponent = hitbox.GetComponent<Hitbox>();
        Vector2 offset = hitboxComponent.m_offset;
        Vector3 position = hitbox.transform.position;
        Quaternion rotation = hitbox.transform.rotation;

        // Do something with the extracted data
        Debug.Log("Name: " + hitbox.transform.name);
        Debug.Log("Offset at frame " + frameIndex + ": " + offset);
        Debug.Log("Position at frame " + frameIndex + ": " + position);
        Debug.Log("Rotation at frame " + frameIndex + ": " + rotation);
    }

    private float GetTimeFromFrame(int frame)
    {
        float frameRate = attackBoxAnimaiton.frameRate;
        Debug.Log(frameRate);
        return frame / frameRate;
    }
```

This code did not give me the desired output. I read from some sites that [SampleAnimation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip.SampleAnimation.html) only applies to transform properties like position and rotation. Based on that I may have not been able to get the field variable of a custom script.

Comment: [`SampleAnimation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip.SampleAnimation.html) should wok for any animated component properties not only `Transform` .. just to confirm the `Offset` refers to the `m_offset` (so just display name difference) or are they by any chance two different things?

Comment: @derHugo Yes, `Offset` refers to `m_offset`. The image that I've attached to the post shows offset values for the time 0.02 seconds and the values are 1.93 and 1.22 for x and y respectively.  This code returns (0,0) for the `Offset`.